# Using Copycat with one-shot abilities

Tags: smash-up

In the Science Fiction Double Feature expansion, the card Copycat allows you to copy the ability of another's player minion for a turn.

> Choose another player's minion in play. This card has the same ability as that minion until the end of the turn.

However, the timing of the copy is not clear. When I play Copycat it's ability activates. If I copy an ability that says "You may draw a card", does it activate again allowing me to draw a card? Or can I only effectively copy Ongoing abilities (and those that remain for the rest of the turn, like "you may play an extra minion")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of Copycat is to allow you to use another minion's ability. Making it impossible to copy most minion's ability makes makes no sense to me, and it makes no sense to the others with whom I've played either.

Keep in mind that you're already limited to abilities of other player's minions in play (something you have no control over), and that ongoing abilities and talents only work for your turn. This offsets the ability to have some flexibility in the effect of the minions ability.

We have it come into play with the abilities of the minion it copies. Playing a Copycat masquerading as an Enchantress ("Draw a card.") would have you draw a card, because it is an Enchantress as far as any can tell (except in name and power).

It's not really an "again" type of situation. You get to use the Enchantress's ability once. Just like the Enchantress did.

Comment: By the way, I since had a look at the factions, and very few have any abilities that would be usable by Copycat if it only copied ongoing abilities of minions. There's no doubt in my mind that it clones one-shot abilities.

Answer (score 0):

The copying part of Copy Cat is done on play, so yes you would get 'Enchantresses' ability to draw a card. However, to draw that card you'd have to play that card, just like any other card. Since you're not playing it again, you don't get to draw a card.

Copy cat is still really good, you get Talent's, Specials, and On-Going abilities.